# SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter and column family comparator

Tags: cassandra

Am trying to use sstableloader, for a CF created with cql like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d int,
    e set<text>,
    f text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((a, b) c, d))
```

How should I define the column family comparator in SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter ? Or more specific how does it work when a column is defined as a set ?

```
SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter(File directory,
                                   IPartitioner partitioner,
                                   String keyspace,
                                   String columnFamily,
                                   AbstractType<?> comparator,
                                   AbstractType<?> subComparator,
                                   int bufferSizeInMB,
                                   CompressionParameters compressParameters)
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to look at how the row is stored internally by the storage engine -- inserting some sample data, then LISTing it from the cli, should help, as well as reading http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3.

The "right" solution is to [create a CQL-aware Writer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5894).